# How to add date formats on PowerShell Custom Object prop value returns?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

However on the console terminal it works just find and that's the output I want when I extract it to csv or txt file and I check type to see if it was string. Sorry maybe I'm just so new to PS that I am not quite familiar with the syntaxes and what's going on under the hood. anyways here is my Here is my hopeful desperate sad attempt
[Sad Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46RTu.png)

2nd attempt trying to find what I seek from several websites via google search

[Sad attempt 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOGTw.png)

This is the specific problem code sorry for the linking(Lazy)

```
# For testing purposes only i
$SpecifiedSelectObj = $Metadata | Select-Object -Property 'Date taken' | ForEach-Object {
   
    ($_."Date taken").GetType()
    Get-Date $_."Date taken" -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt' 
<# Associated Error
    | Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. Cannot convert value "‎10/‎12/‎2014 ‏‎5:31 pm" to type 
    "System.DateTime". Error: "String '‎10/‎12/‎2014 ‏‎5:31 pm' was not recognized as
    | a valid DateTime."    
#>
```

Thank you and much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please post your problem code directly into your question rather than linking.  Please use the [edit] button to correct this.  Please also read [ask] a good question

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out this to me for my poor question standard etiquette and sorry for linking the image(problem) instead of putting the actual code for analyzing and trying to solve to get the one I want to achieve.

Comment: I'm not sure, but there seems to be maybe some encoding issue with your date string.  When I copy and paste the date from your code I get extra spaces.  If I pipe to `Format-Hex` I see extra bytes `E2 80 8E` `â��10/â��12/â��2014 â��â��5:31 pm`   Perhaps someone with more experience with encoding will have an idea what this is about.

Comment: Oh thank you so much Daniel, the help is greatly appreciated. I will have to check it for myself too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution** - remove format characters using [Unicode category or Unicode block: `\p{}`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#unicode-category-or-unicode-block-p). Use

```
Get-Date ($_."Date taken" -replace "\p{Cf}", '') -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt'
```

**Explanation** (with an auxiliary script):

```
Function Get-CodePoint {
    param(
        # named or positional or pipeline: a string to analyse
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        $someString
    )
    ([char[]]$someString |
        ForEach-Object { "0x{0:x2}" -f [int]$_ }) -join ','
}

# Analysis
$dateStringCopyPaste = '‎10/‎12/‎2014 ‏‎5:31 pm'
Write-Verbose "Analysis: $(Get-CodePoint -someString $dateStringCopyPaste)" -Verbose
# $dateStringCopyPaste | Format-Hex -Encoding BigEndianUnicode -Verbose

# Solution:- remove format characters using Unicode category: \p{}
$dateRef = [datetime]::Now
$dateString = $dateStringCopyPaste -replace "\p{Cf}", ''
if ( [datetime]::TryParse( $dateString, [ref]$dateRef ) ) {
    Get-Date $dateRef -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt'
} else {
    Write-Verbose "Solution: $(Get-CodePoint -someString $dateString)" -Verbose
}
```

Output in the analysis phase:

```
VERBOSE: Analysis:
0x200e,0x31,0x30,0x2f,0x200e,0x31,0x32,0x2f,0x200e,0x32,0x30,0x31,0x34,0x20,0x200f,0x200e,0x35,0x3a,0x33,0x31,0x20,0x70,0x6d
```

Those problematic characters `0x200e` and `0x200f` are

```
CodePoint  Category Description
---------  -------- -----------
U+200F    Cf-Format Right-To-Left Mark
U+200E    Cf-Format Left-To-Right Mark
```

**Output**: `.\SO\69156391.ps1`

```
VERBOSE: Analysis:
0x200e,0x31,0x30,0x2f,0x200e,0x31,0x32,0x2f,0x200e,0x32,0x30,0x31,0x34,0x20,0x200f,0x200e,0x35,0x3a,0x33,0x31,0x20,0x70,0x6d
2014-12-10 05:31 PM
```